# CSRF protection Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Can i add CSRF protection to a single form in only one page?

If i make `$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;` in a config file than it is applicable globally in the application but i don't want to make it globally.

Is there any way to make this happen?

I searched and not found any solution.

I tried

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;

$csrf = array(
        'name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
        'hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
);

<input type="hidden" name="<?=$csrf['name'];?>" value="<?=$csrf['hash'];?>" />
```

Comment: if you use Codeigniter 4, just edit the Filters https://codeigniter4.github.io/userguide/libraries/security.html?highlight=csrf#cross-site-request-forgery-csrf

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like this previously using REQUEST_URI, following condition in config file will do the trick:

```
if (stripos($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],'/<path_for_which_you_want_enable_CSRF>/') === TRUE) 
{
    $config['csrf_protection']  = TRUE;
} else
{ 
    $config['csrf_protection']  = FALSE; 
}
```